# Create multiple builds with different CSS and images?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, build

I'm designing a React application that needs to have multiple different builds that use different styles and images, e.g. `header.png` image that differs between different deployed applications.

I've used the `create-react-app` to initialize my project, and I'd love to structure my project so that I have one `common` directory for common CSS/images, and then a custom directory for each build, something along the lines of:

```
node_modules
public
  \--index.html
src
  |--resource
  |    |--common
  |    |    |--img
  |    |    \--styles
  |    |--build1
  |    |    |--img
  |    |    \--styles
  |    \--build2
  |         |--img
  |         \--styles
  |--App.js
  \--index.js
package.json
```

How would I do this in a way where a) the final build would only include files intended for that build and b) I wouldn't have to worry about the current build everywhere in the code.

Comment: so you mean there are multiple apps in a project, and each app has it's own build?

Comment: There is just one app, but it needs to look different for different clients. Images, styles, etc. change, while functionality and content stay the same

Answer (score 1):

There are three things have to do.

### Import path

I assume that your image files in img folder such as jpg, png, SVG will be import into component.

I will use [customize-cra](https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra) and [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired) to override webpack config to configure different import paths depends no different clients.

First you have to install them, then you can create a file called `config-overrides.js` in your project root, and set alias path for your resource such as CSS, SVG icon in config-overrides.

config-overrides.js

```
const path = require('path');
const { addWebpackAlias, override } = require('customize-cra')

const resolveApp = relativePath => path.resolve(__dirname, relativePath)

module.exports.configOverrides = {
  webpack: override(
    addWebpackAlias({
      'common': resolveApp('src/resource/common'),
      '@': resolveApp(`src/resource/${process.env.CLIENT}`)
    })
  ),
}
```

`process.env.CLIENT` is your client name, it will correspond to your folder name such as build1, build2, after setup `webpack alias`, you don’t have to worry about the import path, and you can use only one code.

in your component, you can write this like so

```
import Layout from 'components/Layout';
import { ReactComponent as IconUser } from 'common/img/icon-user.svg';
import styles from '@/styles/header.css';
import { ReactComponent as Logo } from '@/img/logo.svg';
import HeaderImg from '@/img/header.jpg';

function App() {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <div className={styles.header}>
        <img src={HeaderImg>
        <Logo />
        <div>{user.name}</div>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

If your `process.env.CLIENT` is `build1`, '@/img/logo.svg' will reference to `resource/build1/img/logo.svg`, and vice versa

### Development

you can setup different start cmd in your `package.json` to start different clients with different `process.env.CLIENT`

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start:build1": "process.env.CLIENT=build1 npm run start",
    "start:build2": "process.env.CLIENT=build2 npm run start",
  }
}
```

### Production build

Right after the build process finishes, write a command that copies the build folder content to folder of each client, in this way, the codes of different client builds will not cover each other.

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build:build1": "process.env.CLIENT=build1 npm run build && mv build build1",
    "build:build2": "process.env.CLIENT=build2 npm run build && mv build build2",
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is what you want, if you have any problem please let me know, thanks!